# How to create Custom Launch Screen with delay of actual App Loading Time in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, splash-screen, launch

How to create Custom Launch Screen with delay of actual App Loading Time in Swift ?
Can somebody please tell me, how to do that?
I create Custom Launch Screen using Storyboard, but i dont know how to calculate the Application Loading Time.

Comment: Why? Let your users use your app as soon as possible. Don't needlessly make your users wait.

Comment: @rmaddy I want to use actual Loading time.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Application loading time? What did you mean by saying that?

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your question you can set a delay with thread.sleep in the AppDelegate class:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3.0)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Michele